# Count lines following a pattern from file

Tags: shell, unix, grep

For example I have a file `test.json` that contains a series of line containing:

- `header{...}`
- `body{...}`
- other text (as others)
- empty lines

I wanted to run a script that returns the following

```
Counted started on : test.json
- headers : 4
- body : 5
- <others>
Counted finished : <time elapsed>
```

What I got so far is this.

```
count_file() {
    echo "Counted started on : $1"
    #TODO loop
    cat $1 | grep header | wc -l
    cat $1 | grep body | wc -l
    #others
    echo "Counted finished : " #TODO timeElapsed
}
```

Edit:

Edit question and added code snippet

Comment: show some fragment of the actual file

Comment: "Expected result" shouldn't be what you expect from the people answering your question (which shows no effort on your part, currently). It should be the *output* that you expect.

Comment: Instead of `cat $1 |grep header |...` you could simply do `grep header $1 |...`

Answer (score 0):

`Perl on Command Line`

`perl -E '$match=$ARGV[1];open(Input, "<", $ARGV[0]);while(<Input>){ ++$n if /$match/g } say $match," ",$n;' your-file your-pattern`

**For me**
`perl -E '$match=$ARGV[1];open(Input, "<", $ARGV[0]);while(<Input>){ ++$n if /$match/g } say $match," ",$n;' parsing_command_line.pl my`

It counts how many number of pattern **my** are, in my script **parsing_command_line.pl**

**output**

`my 3`

---

**For you**
`perl -E '$match=$ARGV[1];open(Input, "<", $ARGV[0]);while(<Input>){ ++$n if /$match/g } say $match," ",$n;' test.json headers`

**NOTE**
Write all code in **one line** on your command prompt
First argument is **your file**
Second is your **pattern**
This is not a complete **code** since you have to enter all your pattern one-by-one

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the result of a commande in a variable, like:

```
result=`cat $1 | grep header | wc -l`
```

and then print the result:

```
echo "# headers : $b"
```

` is the *eval* operator that let replace the whole expression by the output of the command inside.